# Colocar projeto local Maven como dependência em projeto Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, biblioteca

Tenho esse projeto Maven que possui todas as classes de domínio da aplicação e lógica. Daí criei um projeto externo Gradle de testes onde faço testes de sistema com o Selenium WebDriver.

Para não precisar adicionar todas as classes de domínio no meu projeto gradle, gostaria de adicionar o Maven nas dependências, porém na hora de executar o projeto de testes, lança vários erros em todas as classes que utilizo os domínios.

A questão principal é: como fazer para adicionar o projeto maven como dependência no projeto gradle?

Já tentei colocar

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "../meuProjetoMaven" }
```

no build.gradle e

```
dependencies {

    compile "br:meuProjetomaven"
```

porém me dá essa saída:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':testCompileClasspath'.
>
> Could not find br:meuProjetomaven:.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         file:/C:/Users/pedro/.m2/repository/br/meuProjetomaven//meuProjetomaven-.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/pedro/.m2/repository/br/meuProjetomaven//meuProjetomaven-.jar
>         file:/C:/Users/pedro/git/projeto/br/meuProjetomaven//meuProjetomaven-.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/pedro/git/projeto/br/meuProjetomaven//meuProjetomaven-.jar

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>br</groupId>
<artifactId>meuProjetomaven</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>meuProjetomaven</name>
<description>Descricao</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>br</groupId>
        <artifactId>package-release-framework</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

build.gradle

```
/*
Script de build dos testes para o meuProjetoMaven
**/

/********************************** Repositórios *****************************************/

buildscript {
    repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "http://SomeRepo.com/artifactory/libs-release" }
    maven { url "http://SomeRepo.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot" }

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'br:automacao-gradle:0.1.1'
}
}

repositories {
mavenLocal()

maven { url "http://SomeRepo.com/artifactory/libs-release" }
maven { url "http://SomeRepo.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot" }

}

/*********************************** Build ***********************************************/

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'br.automacao-gradle'

dependencies {
    testCompile "br:automacao-core:0.1.0"
    //compile "br:myMavenProject" << esta linha está comentada pois foi de uma tentativa que não deu certo de utilizar
}

sourceSets{
    main{
    java.srcDirs = []
}
test{
    java.srcDirs = ['src', 'testes']
    resources.srcDirs = ['test-resources']
}
}
```

Comment: Você pode editar a pergunta e postar o `pom.xml` e o `build.gradle` completos?

Comment: @VictorStafusa feito

Comment: Há algum motivo para você usar o maven e o gradle ao invés de apenas usar o gradle?

Comment: @VictorStafusa o projeto maven é um projeto a parte que a equipe está desenvolvendo. O gradle é porque o framework base que eu uso para desenvolver os testes é feito em gradle.

Comment: O que é `br.automacao-gradle` e `br:automacao-core`?

Comment: justamente as dependencias do framework para automação dos testes

Answer (score 1):

O seu arquivo maven tem alguns problemas. Primeiro, retire essas coisas dele:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br</groupId>
            <artifactId>package-release-framework</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

Sugiro também trocar o ISO-8859-1 por UTF-8. O formato ISO-8859-1 é horroroso. Mas isso daí já é assunto para uma outra pergunta.

Finalmente, esse trecho diz qual é a versão que você está gerando:

```xml
    <groupId>br</groupId>
    <artifactId>meuProjetomaven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
```

Aqui há três problemas. O primeiro é que isso daqui diz que o nome do seu projeto é `br:meuProjetomaven:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` e portanto, tentar utilizar no gradle `br:myMavenProject` não vai funcionar nunca, pois `meuProjetomaven` e `myMavenProject` são nomes bem diferentes.

O segundo é que `SNAPSHOT` só serve para dor-de-cabeça e cria muito mais problemas do que resolve. Eu recomendo não utilizar `SNAPSHOT` nunca. Na minha opinião, esse negócio de `SNAPSHOT` jamais deveria ter sido inventado.

O terceiro problema é que você está gerando um arquivo `war`, e não um arquivo `jar`. Um arquivo `war` não foi feito para ser utilizado como dependência por coisa alguma, foi feito para ser implantado em um servidor de aplicação e nada mais do que isso. Dessa forma, não há como utilizá-lo como dependência no gradle.

Usar `compile` ou `testCompile` é para colocar o JAR no classpath. Apenas JAR, e não WAR ou EAR. Arquivos WAR e EAR nunca devem estar no classpath de coisa alguma.

Se o que você quer é apenas testar a sua aplicação no Selenium, então o seu pacote de testes não deveria ter acesso às suas classes de domínio e deveria acessar a sua aplicação apenas via HTTP. você monta um script em algum lugar que implanta a sua aplicação, sobe ela, usa o gradle para rodar o teste e desce a aplicação. Ou então, dentro do próprio teste você faz esse processo. Existe forma de subir a aplicação e implantar dentro do gradle, mas isso depende muito do tipo de servidor que você tem e já seria tópico para uma outra pergunta.

Por outro lado, se o que você quer é acessar as classes de domínio para fazer testes de unidade, você deverá adicionar os JARs (e não WARs ou EARs) de dependência no `compile` ou `testCompile`.

Se você quer uma abordagem híbrida, onde você testa a aplicação via Selenium e tem acesso às classes de domínio, recomendo separar as duas coisas. Se não puder ou não quiser separar, a solução seria dividir o seu WAR em dois: Um arquivo JAR com as classes de domínio e um arquivo WAR que depende do JAR e o deixa em um formato que possa ser implantado como aplicação. O seu teste declararia como `testCompile` esse JAR e o Selenium acessaria o conteúdo do WAR apenas via HTTP.

Comment: Não usar snapshots nunca no Maven? Fiquei curioso... será que consigo perguntar sobre isso de maneira aceitável?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Já me ferrei muito com snapshot e o dia que decidi bani-los de vez, tudo ficou mais fácil. Também já vi outras pessoas contraindicando os snapshots. No entanto, apenas relatando experiências e dizendo que "ouvi falar", eu não conseguiria ainda elaborar uma boa resposta nisso se você abrir uma pergunta nova.

Comment: Pois ainda não consegui pensar uma pergunta que não seja ampla ou baseada em opiniões, então vai ter um tempinho para pensar na resposta